# Makes hosting read strange file extensions

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Sorry if the question is not clear. I'm not a programmer :D.

I use wamp to develop a site locally and files with strange extensions (e.g. .php_news_id_121) can work perfectly in localhost.
However, when I upload them to a live server, in the same folder with a Wordpress installation, the browser can't read the files anymore.
The browser just shows a bunch of html codes without interpreting them into a webpage. 
Although these files have strange extensions, they are just html files.

Please let me know if how to make the hosting server behave like Wamp which reads the files with strange extensions and generate a complete webpage.

Comment: What is the use of doing like this??

Answer (score 2):

If your live server is Apache, set httpd.conf file under “/etc/apache2/”

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .myext
```

Comment: It worked though I found the apache setting in Cpanel